# why sqlite gives different time rather than current time?

Tags: sqlite

I have created a table with schema `cur_date date, cur_time time`. I want to insert the current time and date into the table. When I do so with

```
INSERT INTO timeDemo VALUES(date(),time());
```

and

```
SELECT* FROMtimeDemo
```

it returns a row with current date but a different time. I executed this query at `4:03 PM` of system time, but the row has `10:22` .

How can I fix it? I run these from cmd.exe .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a local time you should use `date` modifiers:

```
INSERT INTO timeDemo VALUES(date('now', 'localtime'),time('now', 'localtime'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) says that the date/time functions return UTC by default:

```
> select time('now'), time('now', 'localtime');
11:00:05|12:00:05
```